# Is the Kinect SDK out?

Tags: sdk, kinect, release

I wanna work on Kinect, about a month ago I read that the Kinect SDK for Windows is out, but [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/)
I found nothing , is it out , or do we still have to wait for the SDK?
and if it's not , when will it be released?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Microsoft has released [Kinect SDK 1.0 on 1st of February 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/).

If you want to get started, you can [watch the videos here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart).

If you are still on Microsoft Kinect Beta 2, you can [watch these videos here instead](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/).

Answer (score 3):

Is out now! However, its limited mate. No fine motor recognition and if your developing for commercial purposes, forget about it.

Dont get me wrong... Its great to play around with and tinker with its functionality, but if youre looking for something more, check out OpenCV... that is if you can proggy with C, C++ or Python.

Good luck mate.

Comment: Confirmed at Tech.Ed Australia that Microsoft plan to bring out the commercial version of the SDK by years end. Huzzah!

Answer (score 2):

To get latest official information about Microsoft kinect SDK for windows, subscribe to official page of Kinect for Windows SDK Beta:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/

Answer (score 2):

The kinect sdk 1.0 is out now. You can download it from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Kinect SDK v1.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx)

Easy upgrade from SDK v1.0 and includes:

- Joint/Bone Orientation
- Improved Face Tracking

There are some nice samples too. I am sure the next release will be around the corner too.